# How to move a point across the screen in PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a point move around the screen using PyQt5. I want the point to always be moving. I'm not sure where to place the code to change it's velocity. Is there some method whose code is executed constantly?

Here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLabel, QWidget)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor, QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class MouseTracker(QWidget):
    distance_from_target = 0
    mouse_x_pos = 0
    mouse_y_pos = 0
    target_x_pos = 500
    target_y_pos = 250

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 1000, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Mouse Tracker')
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.resize(500, 40)
        self.show()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        distance_from_target = round(((event.y() - self.target_y_pos)**2 + (event.x() - self.target_x_pos)**2)**0.5)
        self.label.setText('Coordinates: (%d : %d)' % (event.x(), event.y()) + "   Distance from target: " + str(distance_from_target))       
        self.mouse_x_pos = event.x()
        self.mouse_y_pos = event.y()
        self.update()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.target_x_pos = event.x()
        self.target_y_pos = event.y()
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        q = QPainter()
        q.begin(self)
        q.drawLine(self.mouse_x_pos, self.mouse_y_pos, self.target_x_pos, self.target_y_pos)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = MouseTracker()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What I want to do is make `target_x_pos` constantly increment, regardless of whether the mouse is moving or clicked. How do I do this?

I can't implement a loop because then nothing else would be responsive. Is this where threading comes in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to implement a `QTimer`, every time it is triggered you must update the desired position, in addition to using `self.update()` to update the drawing.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLabel, QWidget)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter


class MouseTracker(QWidget):
    distance_from_target = 0
    mouse_x_pos = 0
    mouse_y_pos = 0
    target_x_pos = 500
    target_y_pos = 250
    vel = 60  # pixels per second

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MouseTracker, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.initUI()
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.changePosition)
        self.timer.start(1000 / self.vel)

    def changePosition(self):
        self.target_x_pos += 1
        self.update()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 1000, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Mouse Tracker')
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.resize(500, 40)
        self.show()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        distance_from_target = round(
            ((event.y() - self.target_y_pos) ** 2 + (event.x() - self.target_x_pos) ** 2) ** 0.5)
        self.label.setText(
            'Coordinates: (%d : %d)' % (event.x(), event.y()) + "   Distance from target: " + str(distance_from_target))
        self.mouse_x_pos = event.x()
        self.mouse_y_pos = event.y()
        self.update()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.target_x_pos = event.x()
        self.target_y_pos = event.y()
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        q = QPainter()
        q.begin(self)
        q.drawLine(self.mouse_x_pos, self.mouse_y_pos, self.target_x_pos, self.target_y_pos)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MouseTracker()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you want to test with Thread I show you the following code, I have not had problems in refreshing the values.

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLabel, QWidget)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter


class MyThread(QThread):
    signal = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.value = None
        self.vel = None

    def setValue(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def setVelocity(self, vel):
        self.vel = vel

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.value += 1
            self.signal.emit(self.value)
            time.sleep(1/self.vel)


class MouseTracker(QWidget):
    distance_from_target = 0
    mouse_x_pos = 0
    mouse_y_pos = 0
    target_x_pos = 500
    target_y_pos = 250
    vel = 60  # pixels per second

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MouseTracker, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.initUI()
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.thread = MyThread(self)
        self.thread.setValue(self.target_x_pos)
        self.thread.setVelocity(self.vel)
        self.thread.signal.connect(self.updatePosition)
        self.thread.start()

    def updatePosition(self, val):
        self.target_x_pos = val
        self.update()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 1000, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Mouse Tracker')
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.resize(500, 40)
        self.show()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        distance_from_target = round(
            ((event.y() - self.target_y_pos) ** 2 + (event.x() - self.target_x_pos) ** 2) ** 0.5)
        self.label.setText(
            'Coordinates: (%d : %d)' % (event.x(), event.y()) + "   Distance from target: " + str(distance_from_target))
        self.mouse_x_pos = event.x()
        self.mouse_y_pos = event.y()
        self.update()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.target_x_pos = event.x()
        self.thread.setValue(self.target_x_pos)
        self.target_y_pos = event.y()
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        q = QPainter()
        q.begin(self)
        q.drawLine(self.mouse_x_pos, self.mouse_y_pos, self.target_x_pos, self.target_y_pos)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MouseTracker()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This works, but there is a noticeable lag in the movement of the point whenever I move the mouse. How do I make it move at a more or less constant velocity? Do you think the mouseMoveEvent is executing too often and taking up too much resources?

Comment: @Kos 
In my case I do not have that problem.

Comment: Strange. Are you running on a Mac?

Comment: @Kos No, I'm running on linux :P

Comment: I see. I'm on a Mac. Do you think threading will solve the issue?

Comment: I do not think, since the redrawn is what will take, what value have you attached to **vel**