# How to animate a point movement across the screen in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have searched for this for a while and didn't get the results I wanted. I saw [How to move a point across the screen in PyQt5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41732808/how-to-move-a-point-across-the-screen-in-pyqt5) however it as well as the other pages that I saw were describing how to update the GUI with the use of events. In the contrary, I don't want to use any events like mouse-clicking, or pressing any keys. I would like to give to my point the (x, y) - corrdinates from the .txt file and see it moving according to the given values.

Comment: Could you explain what you want in more detail, in the example of the link a line is drawn joining the point pressed with the click of the mouse and the point where the mouse was dragged. In your case, what should be drawn? also shows the information in the .txt

Comment: @eyllanesc I want just a simple point that moves in a plane from one coordinate to another. The .txt file gives the coordinates like (1,1), (2,1), (2,2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the solution of the question it is enough to know that:

- Repainting can be invoked indirectly through update (or repaint).
- To get an animation when the X property varies then the property must be extrapolated between 2 consecutive points and in Qt you can use QXAnimation as QPropertyAnimation.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    pointChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QPoint)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._point = QtCore.QPoint(0, 0)

        self._animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(
            self,
            duration=1000,
            propertyName=b"point",
            targetObject=self,
            startValue=QtCore.QPoint(0, 0),
            endValue=QtCore.QPoint(0, 0),
            finished=self.calculate_next_point,
        )

        points = (
            QtCore.QPoint(10, 100),
            QtCore.QPoint(400, 300),
            QtCore.QPoint(210, 500),
            QtCore.QPoint(500, 210),
            QtCore.QPoint(500, 200),
            QtCore.QPoint(150, 0),
            QtCore.QPoint(150, 100),
            QtCore.QPoint(50, 300),
            QtCore.QPoint(0, 500),
            QtCore.QPoint(110, 350),
        )
        self._points_iter = iter(points)
        self.calculate_next_point()

    def _update_end_point(self, p):
        s = self._animation.endValue()
        self._animation.setStartValue(s)
        self._animation.setEndValue(p)
        self._animation.start()

    def calculate_next_point(self):
        try:
            p = next(self._points_iter)
        except StopIteration:
            print("finished")
        else:
            self._update_end_point(p)

    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(QtCore.QPoint, notify=pointChanged)
    def point(self):
        return self._point

    @point.setter
    def point(self, p):
        self._point = p
        self.pointChanged.emit(p)
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        radius = 10

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)

        rect = QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 2 * radius, 2 * radius)
        rect.moveCenter(self.point)

        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("salmon")))
        painter.drawEllipse(rect)


def main():
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Is it possible to set the same way two points? Like in a snake game?